# Limiting behaviour of a bounded sequence of functions in L^2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of functions on $[0, 1]$ that is bounded in $L^2$. (i.e., $sup_n ||f_n||_2$ < $\infty$). 
Suppose there exists a measurable function $f$ such that : 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \! |f_n - f|dm = 0$.

Show that $f \in L^2$. Does it follow that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$?

I was thinking one could use something similar to the monotone convergence theorem by arguing that 
The square integral of $f$ must be equal to the limit of the square integral of $f_n's$. and since each $f_n$ is bounded so is the integral of $f$, hence $f \in L^2$. 
Although I don't quite see how to do this. 
I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: Are the functions $f_n$ bounded by the same constant? So there is $K>0$ that $\|f_n\|_2 < K$ for any $n$?

Comment: The question only says they are bounded, and I think that is all that matters but I could be wrong.

Comment: Than I think I can give you counter example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from the question, but let assume that there is $K>0$ that $\|f_n\|_2<K$ for any $n$. 
Than
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{|f_n-f|}{2K} dm \geq \int_0^1 \frac{|f_n-f|^2}{4K^2} dm $$

because $ \frac{|f_n-f|}{2K} \leq 1 $ a.e.

So 
$$  2 K\int_0^1|f_n-f| dm \geq \int_0^1 |f_n-f|^2 dm $$ 
But the left side goes to zero(as $n$ goes to $\infty$) so the left side goes to zero as well.

---

Ok now if the assumption I made does not hold.

Take functions $f_n(x) = x^{-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}} \chi_{[\frac1{n^k},1]}(x) $. Where $\chi_A$ is characteristic function of set $A$ and $k$ is sufficiently high so that everything else holds. But if these functions converge than they converge to the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. But $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$ is not in $L^2$. And all of the $f_n$ are bounded.

This is just and idea so there might be an error.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks alot!